# Transferring calculated results from spatial join to original feature class in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, arcgis-10.4, spatial-join

Is there a way to transfer the attributes calculated in a field within a spatial join back into the original feature class using ArcMap?

I am numbering manholes ID's based off a grid system, so each grid cell would have manholes with ID's from 1-n. Each manhole ID also has the grid cell name attached to each ID. Ex:

Grid cell J10:
 Manholes: J10-1, J10-2, J10-3, etc...
Grid cell A5:
 Manholes: A5-1, A5-2, A5-3, etc...

The new ID's are stored in a field called New_ID. After calculating those new ID's, I noticed that the original New_ID field in my original feature class had not updated like it would with a tabular join. And I can't copy and paste my results from the spatial join field into my original feature class New_ID field. Does anyone know if there is a way to update a field in your original feature class using data you calculated in a spatial join?

I am using ArcMap 10.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the feature class created by [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) you have the original FIDs/ObjectIDs. Use these to join data back to the original data.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the problem. Still a bit green on the job here and overlooked that now obvious fix.